# Asp.net button click event handler in update panel executes twice when enter with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, event-handling, updatepanel, enter

I have this on my page

```
<asp:TextBox Text="" ID="txtEmailOApodo" MaxLength="70" runat="server" Width="250px"
            Style="height: 25px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Text="" ID="txtContrasena" MaxLength="50" TextMode="Password" runat="server"
            CssClass="textoLightbox"></asp:TextBox>

 <div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanelLoginIncorrecto">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CustomValidator ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="usuarioExistente_Validation"
                Display="Static" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" ID="vldLogin" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, MsjError_LoginIncorrecto%>">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLoginLightbox" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="tableContent" style="float: right;">
    <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="btnLoginLightbox" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="btnLoginUserControl_Click" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtContrasena.ClientID%>").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {               
            $("#<%=btnLoginLightbox.ClientID%>").click();
        }
    });

    $("#<%=txtEmailOApodo.ClientID%>").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#<%=btnLoginLightbox.ClientID%>").click();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In the code behind i have

```
 protected void btnLoginUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Some code....      
 }
```

I dont know why the btnLoginUserControl_Click executes twice when i have focus on either txtContrasena or txtEmailOApodo and press the enter key.

Comment: i tried adding event.preventDefault or return false; none worked :(

Comment: the keyup function is exectuing twice. I replaced the click() with an alert and the alert shows twice

Answer (score 0):

I have seen double post behavior similar to what you are describing when you have an image on the page with a blank `src` attribute. For example: `<img src="" />`